# Separate PHP 5.2 Nginx Phpbrew

Tags: php, ubuntu, nginx

I am aiming to install secondary php fpm 5.2.17 on a Ubuntu machine running nginx and php 5.6.

I have successfully done this as a test using php 5.4.38 and both versions give the individual phpinfo() on their individual ports.

Despite seemingly installing ok there are 2 issues:

Phpbrew requires 5.3 itself so while using the command

```
phpbrew use 5.2.17
```

actually changes it the version its using it then breaks because it is using 5.2 and not 5.3 giving errors and example switching between the two as

```
# phpbrew list
* (system)
  php-5.4.38
  php-5.3.22
  php-5.2.17
~/.phpbrew/php/php-5.4.38/etc > root@dm-dell01 [php:5.6.11-system]
# phpbrew use 5.2.17
~/.phpbrew/php/php-5.4.38/etc > root@dm-dell01 [php:5.2.17-phpbrew]
# phpbrew list

Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_STRING, expecting T_CONSTANT_ENCAPSED_STRING or '(' in /usr/bin/phpbrew on line 8
~/.phpbrew/php/php-5.4.38/etc > root@dm-dell01 [php:5.2.17-phpbrew]
# phpbrew switch-off
Parse: command not found
phpbrew is switched off.
~/.phpbrew/php/php-5.4.38/etc > root@dm-dell01 [php:5.6.11-system]
# phpbrew list
* (system)
  php-5.4.38
  php-5.3.22
  php-5.2.17
~/.phpbrew/php/php-5.4.38/etc > root@dm-dell01 [php:5.6.11-system]
```

On investigating the relevant files I am also unable to find any php.ini files either. I am looking for this as an alternative as using phpbrew with 5.2 gives

```
# phpbrew config

Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_STRING, expecting T_CONSTANT_ENCAPSED_STRING or '(' in /usr/bin/phpbrew on line 8
~/.phpbrew/php/php-5.4.38/etc > root@dm-dell01 [php:5.2.17-phpbrew]
```

so its impossible to set it up any further.

Comment: PHP 5.2 has been obsolete and unsupported for over five years. Please stop using it.

Comment: Not very helpful, I fully understand its unsupported and only require this to connect to a mysqli 'old_password' database and deliver the results back to the current version.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer was to look for an alternate solution. PHPBrew and numerous forums read have simply cut off 5.2 as old technology and a waste of time supporting for so few users.
I too have wasted enough time as well and moved on to an alternate solution without 5.2.